# How to replace tk8.6 with tk8.5?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python

The title explains pretty much all I need to do. I need a downgrade from tk8.6 to tk8.5 on 14.04.

There is some niche scientific python based software that I need to use, however it is incompatible with tk8.6 and is compatible with tk8.5; download available [here.](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html) Ideally I would like a method that poses minimal risk to my system.

Here are some details that might be useful.

```
me@James:~$ whereis tk
tk: /usr/lib/tk8.6 /usr/include/tk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to downgrade `tk` to 8.5 on 14.04, even if you install `tk8.5`.

This method is not recommended as it's basically installing the 13.10 packages version on a 14.04 system.

First of all, to **restore** your system, the command to use will be:

```
sudo apt-get install blt python-tk
```

Now to downgrade to tk8.5:

1. Install tk8.5:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tk8.5
   ```
2. Download the following debian packages from the 13.10 repo (amd64 in this example but you can choose the i386 for a 32bit system):

   - [blt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/blt/download)
   - [python-tk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/python-tk/download)
3. Open a terminal where you downloaded the two .deb files and type:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i blt_2.4z-7_amd64.deb python-tk_2.7.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Now to check if the right version is available to your python interpreter:

   ```
   $ python
   Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
   [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import Tkinter
   >>> Tkinter.TkVersion
   8.5
   >>> import platform
   >>> platform.release()
   '3.13.0-36-generic'
   >>>
   ```

Comment: Should I open a new question on how do I stop Tkinter updating once I have downgraded or shall we modify this question?

Comment: @GoodGravy: Check this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package). You'll need to lock versions for both `blt` and `python-tk`.